# PyCharm and unittest won't run

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I have a problem with PyCharm 3.0.1 I can't run basic unittests.

Here is my code :

```py
import unittest from MysqlServer import MysqlServer


class MysqlServerTest(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        self.mysqlServer = MysqlServer("ip", "username", "password", "db", port)


    def test_canConnect(self):
        self.mysqlServer.connect()
        self.fail()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here is All the stuff PyCharm give me

> Unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly

It also says

```py
AttributeError: class TestLoader has no attribute '__init__'
```

And the event log :

```
2:14:28 PM Empty test suite
```

The problem is when I run manually the Python file (with PyCharm, as a script)

```
Ran 1 tests in 0.019s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Which is normal I make the test fail on purpose. I am a bit clueless on what is going on.
here more information :

- `Setting`->`Python Integrated Tools`->`Package requirements file`: `<PROJECT_HOME>/src/test`
- Default test runner: Unittests
- pyunit 1.4.1 Is installed

EDIT: Same thing happen with the basic usage from unitests.py

```py
import unittest


class IntegerArithmenticTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
def testAdd(self):  ## test method names begin 'test*'
    self.assertEquals((1 + 2), 3)
    self.assertEquals(0 + 1, 1)

def testMultiply(self):
    self.assertEquals((0 * 10), 0)
    self.assertEquals((5 * 8), 40)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I ran into this in Pycharm when my `setUpClass` threw an exception.

Comment: New answer added below that might help in your case. Can you please verify?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is probably because you did not set your testing framework correctly in the settings dialogue.

[image]

Comment: After a JVM change,(Open to Sun) A couple reboot, and the usage of py.test instead of unittests (that still not work). I can run my test inside pycharm with the py.test framework. Also look like i had some deprecated package i had to update via the setuptools.

Comment: I am seeing what I think is the same base problem on pycharm 3.x.  On the previous versions of pycharm my `if __name__ == '__main__'` block was executed.  Now it is not.  This messes up some tests when run under the debugger.

Comment: This worked for me but it took a while for PyCharm to start running Unittests instead of pytest, for whatever reason.  No restarts, but multiple debug launches.

Answer (score 71):

Although this wasn't the case with the original poster, I'd like to note that another thing that will cause this are test functions that don't begin with the word 'test.'

```
class TestSet(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_will_work(self):
        pass

    def will_not_work(self):
        pass
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem and I laughed out loud when I realized it.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely a pycharm thingy, repeating from above,

- Run --> Edit Configurations.
- select the instances of the test, and press the red minus button.

Comment: screenshot would help

Answer (score 5):

I have the exact same problem. It turned out that the fact of recognizing an individual test was related to the **file name**. In my case, `test_calculate_kpi.py`, which PyCharm didn't recognize as a test when renamed to `test_calculate_kpis.py`, was immediately recognized.

Comment: Renaming worked for me too. In my case, there was more than one file in the project with the same name and renaming it to be unique fixed it.

Comment: Yes, the file which contains the test should start with "test_"

Answer (score 1):

### 4 steps to generate html reports with PyCharm and most default test runners (py.test, nosetest, unittest etc.):

1. make sure you give your test methods a **prefix 'test'** (as stated before by others), e.g. `def test_run1()`
2. the widespread example code from test report package‘s documentation is

   ```
   import unittest
   import HtmlTestRunner

   class TestGoodnessOfFitTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_run1(self):
     ...

   if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='t.html'))
   ```

   This code is usually located in a test class file which contains all the unittests and the "main"-catcher code. This code continuously yielded the warning `Empty test suite` for me. Therefore, **remove all the if __name__ ... code**. The file now only contains the `TestGoodnessOfFitTests` class. Now, additionally
3. **create a new main.py** in the same directory of the test class file and use the following code:

   ```
    import unittest
    import HtmlTestRunner
    test_class = TestGoodnessOfFitTests()
    unittest.main(module=test_class, 
    testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='t.html'))
   ```
4. **Remove your old run configurations**, right-click on your main.py and press `Run 'main'`. Verify correct settings under `Preferences -> Python Integrated Tools -> Default test runner` (in my case py.test and nose worked)

**Output**:

```
Running tests... 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 test_gaussian_dummy_kolmogorov_cdf_1 (tests.evaluation_tests.TestGoodnessOfFitTests) ... OK (1.033877)s

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0:00:01

OK



Generating HTML reports...
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem, I felt the workspace was not properly refreshed. Even I did File->Synchronize(Ctrl+Aly+y). But that wasn't the solution. I just renamed my test python file name and again I tried executing the code, it started worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The file was named `test_exercise_detectors.py` (note the plural "detectors") and it was in a packed named `test_exercise_detectors`. Changing the name of the file to `test_exercise_detector.py` (singular "detector") fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Adding

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This actually explicitly skips unit tests skipped in my case.  `__name__` doesn't always equal `"__main__"` in PyCharm debug mode.