# Python: empty test suite

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have tried so many ways([Pycharm and unittest does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251386/pycharm-and-unittest-does-not-work) 
) to solve the problem.
But I am still a bit clueless on what is going on here.
I can't run basic unittests. Thank you in advance.

```
#test_names.py
import unittest
from Practices.SomeFunction import get_formatted_name
class NameTestCase(unittest.TestCase):  
    """test get_fotmatted_name()"""

    def test_first_last_name(self):
        formatted_name = get_formatted_name('janis', 'joplin')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Janis Joplin')

unittest.main()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtmAR.png)

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIjjY.png)

Answer (score 1):

just need to add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

then

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm it isn't necessary to add the line 
`unittest.main()`
If you remove it, it should work fine.